# Solving an integral equation over $L^2$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a relatively simple integral equation that I've been struggling with. I'm interested in it because I'd like to find the eigenspace of an eigenvalue of a compact operator in $L^2$. The equation I'd like to solve is this:

$$
\frac{4}{3}f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} f(y)(1-2y-2x)dy.
$$
The thing on the right is precisely the (compact and self-adjoint) operator I'm interested in. I worked out that its operator norm is $4/3$, so $\pm 4/3$ is an eigenvalue of the operator. Now I just have to find an $f$ that satisfies the above. I looked at differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, which gives the much less intimidating

$$
\frac{4}{3}f'(x) = -2 \int_{0}^{1} f(y) dy.
$$
Then I solved that and got the span of some linear function as my solution and it was all fine and dandy until I realized that this method doesn't work, because after differentiating we lose a constant factor, so upon plugging in the "solution" we get that the sides of the original expression are off by a constant. I'd really appreciate any help in solving this integral equation so that I can move on with the rest of this question. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The last equation implies $f=ax+b$ then you have two equations and two unknowns. I don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: Like I said, when you differentiate both sides you're risking that after solving the last equation, your solution becomes off by a constant when you plug it into the original integral. I solved the two equations and unknowns and that's exactly what happened.

Comment: Why don't you update your post with your work? What you're describing should be impossible because two linear equations with two unknowns should be exactly solvable.

Comment: Yep, you're so right - I messed up when I computed its operator norm. Honestly I'm thinking about deleting this question because it seems a bit dumb to have a post about an equation lacking a nontrivial solution.